# How do residuals affect the t-statistic?

Tags: regression, t-test

Could a t-statistic for a simple regression relationship with a smaller sum of squared residuals but a smaller or less positive slope be larger than that of a plot with a larger sum of squared residuals and a large slope?

Comment: Please edit your question to include information about what you mean by the "t-stat of a plot."

Comment: For t-statistics, the effect (aka observed slope - hypothesized slope) is the numerator and the standard error of the observed slope is the denominator. So, in a way, a steeper slope with higher error can have the same (or higher/ or lower) t-statistics compared to a shallower slope with lower error. However, your answer didn't even specify the t-statistics to be equal, instead you've pretty much let everything (t, slope, and error) vary, in that case the results are as good as anyone's guess.